# PHP imap_open not working

Tags: php

I'm getting an error:

> Warning: imap_open() [function.imap-open]: Couldn't open stream {pop3.live.com:995/pop3/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX in /home/.../imap.php on line 3

when using code:

```
$mbox = imap_open('{pop3.live.com:995/pop3/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX', '<user>', '<pass>');
```

Comment: check your imap function name in imap.php

Comment: Do you get any useful output from doing a `print_r(imap_errors());` after the imap_open() call fails?

Answer (score 2):

Your URL has pop3 for a sub-domain. Are you sure that IMAP is available (ports 143 or 993 open)?

Doing a quick search, it looks like imap has to be enabled on your live.com account. Are you able to IMAP to the server using a standard mail client, like Thunderbird?

Also, you are pointing to pop3.live.com on port 995, which is a POP3 port, not an IMAP port.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was `{domain:110/pop3/novalidate-cert}INBOX` that helped me in fixing both the CLOSED IMAP connection broken (server response) and Certificate failure for domain.

Confirm your ports and also whether you have ssl enabled using

```
openssl s_client -crlf -connect your-domain-name:port-number
```